# JSON mapping exception

Tags: java, angularjs, json, resteasy

I am trying to send json data to my JAVA class but getting an error

"Failed executing POST IntakeFormSections/PostData: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of org.json.JSONObject out of START_ARRAY token"

Controller:

```
var datanew =  angular.toJson($scope.data);
 $http({

url :"http://localhost:8080/......IntakeFormSections/PostData",

      method: 'POST',
      data : datanew,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/Json'},

      })};
```

JAVA Code:

```
@POST
@Path("/PostData")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public String UpdateSiteVisitInfo(JSONObject data) throws JSONException {
System.out.println("++++++++++");
System.out.println(data);
return null;}
```

Comment: What is the content of datanew while you are requesting?

Comment: `out of START_ARRAY token` probably `datanew` starts with a `[` and not with  `{` as requested to be parsed as `JSONObject` in your method signature.

Comment: content of datanew is this json:-                                                                     "questions": [{
   "Id": 1,
   "description": "Submitter Contact Information",
   "type": "hidden",
   "required": "false",
   "subquestions1": [{
     "Id": "a",
     "description": "ID",
     "type": "text",
     "name": "id",
     "patternType": "alphanumeric",
     "required":"false"

    }, {
     "Id": "b",
     "description": "Name",
     "type": "text",
     "name": "user",
     "patternType": "text",
     "required":"false",
     "length":100

    }]

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is in wrong format.

It should be like this.

```
[{ "Id": 1, "description": "Submitter Contact Information", "type": "hidden", "required": "false", "subquestions1": [{ "Id": "a", "description": "ID", "type": "text", "name": "id", "patternType": "alphanumeric", "required":"false" }, { "Id": "b", "description": "Name", "type": "text", "name": "user", "patternType": "text", "required":"false", "length":100 }]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a list of JSONObjects as datanew, but in controller it is mapped to single JSONObject, please change controller argument type to accept list of JSONObjects.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you are sending an array with one JSONObject element. That means you either should have a an argument of JSONObject[] array then retrieve the first element or Send a single object to the endpoint.